# Is there a way to reserve a variable used by the operation in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this issue in my c# MVC App where i have a receipt and this receipt has a receipt number and i select the last receipt number inserted in the database and add 1 to it, the problem appears when 2 users submitting the receipt at the same time. What happens is that they both get the same receipt number and they both insert into the database, unfortunately one is inserted and the other gives exception and rollback the whole operation. So my question is there a way to prevent this from happening, in other words reserve a receipt number taken by user, so it won’t be used by the other user.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Typically receipt IDs are unique and have an identity which would make it impossible to have duplicates. Make sure you set up your database column properly to handle such scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

If using sql server you should probably use an IDENTITY column.  Another option would be to use a GUID as the key.

So you need to reset the receipt number for each new year?  You could make a separate call to get the receipt number first without doing inserts into other tables.  This would reserve a number and return immediately.  You could use an identity column for this, either a separate table per year or reset the identity value and truncate at the start of each new year.  Or you could have a table for Ids with Year and ReceiptNumber as the PK and insert a new row with incrementing receipt number by one.

Comment: I can’t use identity since the receipt number serial restarts to zero at the beginning of the year.